# BigQuery Table Decorators with Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, sql

I'm having some trouble using table decorators using Standard SQL. However, the same concept with Legacy SQL syntax works for me. Is this a bug? Here is an example.

(A) The following query works without any issue

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [some-project-name:some_dataset.some_table_name@<time1>-<time2>]`

(B) The following query returns back with an error message
`Error: Table "some-project-name.some_dataset.some_table_name@<time1>-<time2>" cannot include decorator`

`` SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `some-project-name.some_dataset.some_table_name@<time1>-<time2>` ``

## Notes:

- Query (A) has Use Legacy SQL box **checked**.
- Query (B) has Use Legacy SQL box **unchecked**.
- `<time1>` is absolute and is the creation time in of the table in milliseconds since Unix epoch.
- `<time2>` is the current time stamp in milliseconds

## UPDATE:

As Mikhail pointed out, this feature is not available for Standard SQL. It has been requested [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=827&q=label%3DFeature-Request%20standard%20sql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for table decorators in standard SQL is planned but not yet implemented. To view the details of the feature request, see: [BigQuery feature request tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=827). You can click the Vote for this issue and get email notifications icon (the star) to register your support for the feature.

See more at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators

Answer (score 10):

Good news: it's now implemented.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax

```
SELECT *
FROM t
  FOR SYSTEM TIME AS OF '2017-01-01 10:00:00-07:00';
```

Comment: saviour! saviour! saviour!